# Как сделать выравнивание картинок по нижнему краю и прижать их к тексту?

Tags: html, css, css3

Добрый день! Есть `div` следующего вида:

```css
.wrapper,
.wrapper ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div><img src="/img/inf/1.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div><img src="/img/info/2.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div><img src="/img/info/3.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Как выровнять картинки по нижнему краю и прижать их к тексту?

Comment: Мне вот интересно по нижнему краю чего?

Answer (score 0):

У `li` задайте:

```
.wrapper ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Отступ идет от элемента `p`. Чтобы убрать его:

```
.wrapper ul li p{
  margin-top:0;
}
```

```css
.wrapper,
.wrapper ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.wrapper ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
.wrapper ul li p{
  margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div><img src="/img/inf/1.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div><img src="/img/info/2.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div><img src="/img/info/3.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение с применением flexbox:

```css
.wrapper,
.wrapper ul {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.wrapper ul li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div><img src="https://dreamgold.ua/image/catalog/lazyrite/souvenirs/3057.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>сложность</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div><img src="https://dreamgold.ua/image/catalog/lazyrite/souvenirs/3058_1.jpg" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>не в выборе</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div><img src="https://dreamgold.ua/image/catalog/lazyrite/souvenirs/3057_1.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" /></div>
      <p>а в количестве вариантов</p>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
```